# Limits when a series is inside a continuous function

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I was solving a problem and got down to this:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \arctan\left(\frac{\sum_{k=0}^n-\frac{1}{1+k^2}}{\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{k}{1+k^2}}\right)$$
After this, I said that, since the bottom series diverges and the upper one converges, the result is $0$. But the person who gave the question asked me why am I allowed to swap limit and summation.
I think he meant take the limit inside the function and then distribute it on the both the numerator and denominator, but I am not sure, please confirm.
In the case he meant what I have understood, though, I don't really know the answer. Can someone hint me elements of it please? (my knowledge base is Calc1 and what I have accumulated thus far of Calc 2 material)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can swap the limit and the function because the arc tangent function is *continuous*. Then you have the limit of a ratio such that the numerator is bounded, while the denominator diverges to infinity.

Hence your limit is $$\arctan(0)=0.$$

---

You might as well use that $|\arctan x|\le|x|$ and squeeze.

Comment: I didn't know that inequality, thank you. Is there somewhere where I can read about why continuity allows us the swapping and why there are conditions in the first place?

Comment: @Luyw: continuity essentially says that the value of the function at the limit equals the limit of the values of the function, i.e. precisely that the limit and function commute.

Answer (score 1):

As $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2+1}=\frac{1}{2}(1+\pi \coth \pi)$$ is finite
$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k}{k^2+1}$ is divergent so the required limit needs to be
$L=\tan^{-1}(0)=0.$

Comment: Hello Dr. Ahmad, my question was more about why I could get the limit inside the function. However, since you happened to come to my post, didn't you host a pdf about integrals before? I've seen a link to it and tried to access it but it was dead. Do you still possess it? :)

Comment: As stated in  by Yves the continuity of $\tan^{-1}x$ lies behind bringing the the limit inside. Yes, integrals are my favorite items. But usually I attach only a fig file. May be you find this pdf interesting:  arXiv:1411.5169
Cheers.